# Get return value in callback Angular js Directive

Tags: angularjs, callback, angularjs-directive

I have created one directive in Angularjs in which I need to use `callBackMethod`, so that I can call Controller's Function.

Controller's function is called.But Controller's Function is returning some value.I want to get that value in callback function.How to achieve that?

Below is my code for Directive

```
.directive('abcOption', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    template : '<div class="filter-content"></div>',
    replace : true,
    scope : {
            callBackMethod:'&getDisplayName'
    },link: function(scope,element,attrs)
    {
        scope.getDataName =function(dataId)
        {
            scope.callBackMethod(dataId);
        };
}
    };
});
```

Below Code is for  Controller function

```
$scope.getDisplayName = function(columnName) {
return 'abc';
};
```

It's small snippet of the code. Controller function is called but I am not getting return value in directive function. I am getting `undefined` in console log if I log `scope.callBackMethod(dataId)`;

How to get return value using `callBackMethod` in Directive?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While calling the controller's function from inside a directive with an isolate scope, you need to pass an object:

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div abc-option get-display-name="getDisplayName(columnName)"></div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.getDisplayName = function(columnName) {        
        return 'abc';
    };
}
app.directive('abcOption', function($compile,$timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        template : '<div class="filter-content">abc</div>',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            callBackMethod:'&getDisplayName'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){            
            /* send an object to the function */
            console.log(scope.callBackMethod({columnName:"hurray"}));           
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwbsT/27/)**</kbd>

Comment: I find it really odd that the object property name must be the same as the variable called from the markup. Really threw me off.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from CodeHater works but is (just a little) confusing. So I updated it to make it easier to understand

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{returnVal}}
    <div abc-option callback="setDisplayNameFn(mustBeTheSame)"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.setDisplayNameFn = function(whatever) {        
        $scope.returnVal=  whatever;
    };
}
app.directive('abcOption', function($compile,$timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        template : '<div class="filter-content"><b>directive html<b></div>',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            callBackMethod:'&callback'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){            
            /* send an object to the function */
            console.log(scope.callBackMethod({mustBeTheSame:"value from directive"}));           
        }
    };
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phuyem/nwbsT/248/)

Comment: @CanetRobern : ur welcome, glad there is still people using ng1 like me as of end of 2017. Cheers